# Регулярные выражения / жадные квантификаторы

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String REGEX = "(.*)(\\d{1,2})([-./])(\\d{1,2})(.*)";
    String dayAndMonth = "This year 12.03 i visited Italy";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dayAndMonth);
    if (matcher.matches()){
        String day = matcher.group(2);
        String month = matcher.group(4);
        System.out.println(day+" "+month);
    }
}
```

> Вывод: 2 03

Квантификатор вида {m,n} относится к жадным. Почему тогда ищет минимальное совпадние? Как сделать, чтобы выводило 12 03?

Comment: Да, но `(.*)` - первее, и он как раз жадный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый `(.*)` жадный, он забирает как можно больше символов, отличных от знаков перевода строки.

`.*` сразу же "забирает" целую строку (т.е. в первую подмаску сохраняется `This year 12.03 i visited Italy`), потом начинается "backtracking": движок пытается найти совпадение для `\d{1,2}`, "отдавая" символ за символом от конца строки к началу. Таким образом, он добирается до `3`, но последующие подшаблоны не совпадают, однако, когда движок добирается до `2`, `2.03 i visited Italy` возвращается в качестве валидного совпадения для шаблона `(\\d{1,2})([-./])(\\d{1,2})(.*)`.

[Тут можно проверить, что конкретно происходит](https://regex101.com/r/NrLnjj/1/debugger).

Лучше всего избавиться от жадного шаблона `(.*)` и использовать `Matcher#find()` вместо `Matcher#matches` для поиска частичного совпадения:

```
final String REGEX = "(\\d{1,2})[-./](\\d{1,2})";
String dayAndMonth = "This year 12.03 i visited Italy";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dayAndMonth);
if (matcher.find()){
    String day = matcher.group(1);
    String month = matcher.group(2);
    System.out.println(day+" "+month);
}
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/Mb113B)

Ну, можно конечно просто сделать первый `.*` ленивым, и дело с концом:

```
final String REGEX = "(.*?)(\\d{1,2})([-./])(\\d{1,2})(.*)";
                         ^
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/bS4Mki). Но это выражение менее эффективно.

Comment: а ещё можно добавить квантификатор границы слова перед первой цифрой (если это допускает задача и используемый движок). а ещё можно искать не-цифру перед первой цифрой или начало строки: `(^|.*[^0-9])...`

Comment: Тут можно даже `String REGEX = "(?<!\\d)(\\d{1,2})[-./](\\d{1,2})(?!\\d)";` предложить - вдруг эти даты "приклеились" к буквам?

Comment: (?<!\\d) ? указывает на количество предыдущих символов, которых в этом выражении нет. Квантификаторов < ! вроде бы же нет. Можете пояснить это выражение?

Comment: @Donatello `(?<!\d)` — блок предварительного просмотра назад, который проверяет наличие цифры сразу же перед текущей позицией, и отменяет совпадение, если находит там цифру. `(?<!\d)` — блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, и он делает то же самое, что и предыдущий шаблон, только проверка осуществляется сразу справа от текущей позиции. `"(?<!\\d)(\\d{1,2})[-./](\\d{1,2})(?!\\d)"` найдёт `22-11` в `abc22-11def`, но не в `ab022-113def`. [См. демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/eYiGLj/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Спасибо большое за подход! Но не будет ли (?<!\d) равнозначно \\D  ? А если нужно найти все даты в строке, существует ли такой подход? upd. просто зациклить проверку find(), вопрос снят

Comment: @Donatello *Но не будет ли `(?<!\d)` равнозначно `\D`* - **не будет**. Блоки предварительного просмотра только проверяют наличие/отсутствие контекста, а обычные шаблоны добавляют найденный текст в буфер совпадения, и, таким образом, не позволяют находить перекрывающиеся (пересекающиеся) совпадения. См. [Демо №1](https://regex101.com/r/eYiGLj/2) и [Демо №2](https://regex101.com/r/eYiGLj/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Вы не подскажете почему это не работает? **(?<=\s|^)**

Comment: @Donatello `(?<=\s|^)` — блок просмотра назад, который требует присутствия начала строки в данной позиции в строке или пробельного символа сразу же перед текущей позицией. Почему не работает — не знаю, наверное, нет у вас в строке пробела перед искомым совпадением или оно не в начале строки. Кстати, вместо `(?<=\s|^)` лучше использовать `(?<!\S)`.